# How do I update width , height after object was added to the scene? Three.PlaneGeometry ( width,height,1,1)

Tags: three.js, geometry, updating

The application displays photos.
When the user clicks on a photo I want to change its size and location
Changing the location works with this code:
photo.position.y=700;
photo.position.x=700;
but I do not know how to change width and height which where set using:
Three.PlaneGeometry ( width,height,1,1)
( I do not want to move the camera nor frustrom )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've created your `Mesh`, you can modify its `scale` parameter.

```
var imageGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1, 1, 1); // Create a 1x1 plane
var imageFrame = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material); // Build mesh with geometry

// Now you set up the desired dimensions of the resulting mesh
imageFrame.scale.x = 2;
imageFrame.scale.y = 1.5;
```

This will give you a mesh that's scaled up, and its final dimensions are 2 x 1.5. You shouldn't need to alter the `PlaneGeometry` after you first create it; to keep things simple, start with a 1x1, and scale the Mesh instead.

Comment: That took all of ten seconds to code test verify. Thanlk you!

Comment: No problem, @Pixelsmart. If you found the answer useful, don't forget to accept it and/or vote on it :)